# Why does this (mostly) empty Perl subroutine return an empty string?

Tags: perl

Here is a Perl program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub f {
  foreach (()) { }
}

print Dumper(f());
```

This outputs:

```
$VAR1 = '';
```

Since no value is explicitly returned from `f`, and no expressions are evaluated inside it, shouldn't the result be `undef`? Where did the empty string come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since no value is explicitly returned from `f`, and no expressions are evaluated inside it, shouldn't the result be `undef`?

Nope. [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) says the return value is unspecified:

> If no `return` is found and if the last statement is an expression, its value is returned. If the last statement is a loop control structure like a `foreach` or a `while`, the returned value is unspecified.

"Unspecified" is short for "we're not going to document the exact behavior because we could change it at any time and you shouldn't rely on it." Right now, it returns `PL_no` as [LeoNerd explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31462611/176646); in a future Perl version, it could return `undef`, or something else altogether.

Answer (score 13):

It hasn't *quite* returned the empty string; it has returned "false", an internal Perl value (called `PL_no`). This false value is numerically zero but stringily empty. `Data::Dumper` can't represent it directly as `PL_no` and so chooses a representation which will work.

Other ways you can generate it:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper(1 eq 2)'
$VAR1 = '';
```

Comment: Do you know why "false" is returned rather than any other value?

Comment: In list context the returned value is the (truthy) single-element list `(PL_no)`, how is that the right thing? The logical value to return would be `undef`.